Why do I get an error as "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>'"?
I was running unit test in flutter and I am getting error as
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
The related code snippet is as follows where I am trying to read data from the firebase.
 factory TimerSessionModel.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;
    return TimerSessionModel(
      selfRef: snapshot.reference,
      activeExecutionRef: data['activeExecutionRef'],
      autoStartNextTimer: data['autoStartNextTimer'] as bool,
      ownerRef: data['ownerRef'],
      timerRefs: data['timerRefs'],
      title: data['title'] as String,
    );
  }

Here timerRefs is a list of document references, where the problem is pointing to.
I tried to run the unit test and gives me and error as above mentioned

https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#invalid-casts

You need to convert your List type to <DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>.
    factory TimerSessionModel.fromSnapshot(
  DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
  final data = snapshot.data()!;
  // Convert List<dynamic> to List<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>
  List<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>> timerRefs = 
    (data['timerRefs'] as List<dynamic>)
    .map((ref) => ref as DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>)
    .toList();

  return TimerSessionModel(
    selfRef: snapshot.reference,
    activeExecutionRef: data['activeExecutionRef'],
    autoStartNextTimer: data['autoStartNextTimer'] as bool,
    ownerRef: data['ownerRef'],
    timerRefs: timerRefs,
    title: data['title'] as String,
  );
}

